# Java: HashMap works, LinkedHashMap gets Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I started learning Java a few weeks ago, coming from PHP and no other prior language background. I'm used to just using array()...

When I changed my class from a HashMap to a LinkedHashMap I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception,

Using JDK 1.6

***Class LinkedHashMap** - From Oracle [Oracle JDK 1.6 Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)*

> This class provides all of the optional Map operations, and permits null elements. Like HashMap, it provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (add, contains and remove), assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets. Performance is likely to be just slightly below that of HashMap, due to the added expense of maintaining the linked list, with one exception: Iteration over the collection-views of a LinkedHashMap requires time proportional to the size of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a HashMap is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its capacity.

**Does Not Work**

```
@Component("blMenu")
public class MenuProcessor extends AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor {
public  List<Category> topLevelCategories;
public  LinkedHashMap<Category, LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>>> navigationMenu = new LinkedHashMap<Category, LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>>>();
public List<Category> Categories;
public int chunkSize = 5;
public int subCategoriesSize;
public String resultVar;

/**
 * Sets the name of this processor to be used in Thymeleaf template
 */
public MenuProcessor() {
    super("menu");
}

@Override
public int getPrecedence() {
    return 10000;
}

@Override
protected void modifyModelAttributes(Arguments arguments, Element element) {
    CatalogService catalogService = ProcessorUtils.getCatalogService(arguments);

    resultVar = element.getAttributeValue("resultVar");
    String parentCategory = element.getAttributeValue("parentCategory");
    String unparsedMaxResults = element.getAttributeValue("maxResults");

    // TODO: Potentially write an algorithm that will pick the minimum depth category
    // instead of the first category in the list
    List<Category> categories = catalogService.findCategoriesByName(parentCategory);
    if (categories != null && categories.size() > 0) {
        // gets child categories in order ONLY if they are in the xref table and active
        List<Category> subcategories = categories.get(0).getChildCategories();
        if (subcategories != null && !subcategories.isEmpty()) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(unparsedMaxResults)) {
                int maxResults = Integer.parseInt(unparsedMaxResults);
                if (subcategories.size() > maxResults) {
                    subcategories = subcategories.subList(0, maxResults);
                }
            }
        }
        topLevelCategories = subcategories;
        buildMenu(arguments, catalogService);
    }
}

public void buildMenu(Arguments arguments, CatalogService catalogService)
{
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>> chunkSubs;

    for(Category topLvlCat : topLevelCategories)
    {

        Categories = catalogService.findCategoriesByName(topLvlCat.getName());
        List<Category> subCategories = Categories.get(0).getChildCategories();

        if(subCategories != null && !subCategories.isEmpty())
        {
            subCategoriesSize = subCategories.size();
            chunkSubs = chunkSubCategories(subCategories);
            navigationMenu.put(topLvlCat, chunkSubs);
        }
        else
        {
            navigationMenu.put(topLvlCat, null);
        }
    }
    addToModel(arguments, resultVar, navigationMenu);
}


public LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>> chunkSubCategories(List<Category> subCategories)
{
    List<Category> chunkedCategories;
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>> subCategoriesChunked = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<Category>>();

    int iLoop = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = chunkSize - 1;
    int catSize = subCategoriesSize-1;

    if(subCategoriesSize > 1){
    do
    {

        if(end < catSize)
        {
            chunkedCategories = subCategories.subList(start, end);
            subCategoriesChunked.put(iLoop, chunkedCategories);
        }
        else
        {
            end = end - (end-catSize);
            chunkedCategories = subCategories.subList(start, end);
            subCategoriesChunked.put(iLoop, chunkedCategories);
        }

        iLoop = iLoop + 5;
        start = start + chunkSize;
        end = end + chunkSize;

    }while(subCategoriesSize > iLoop);
    }
    return subCategoriesChunked;
}


}
```

But change all the LinkHashMaps to HashMaps and it works.

Stack Trace

> Mar 20, 2013 12:37:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mycompany] in context with path [/site] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'com.mycompany.processor.MenuProcessor' (layout/partials/nav:8)] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.mycompany.processor.MenuProcessor.buildMenu(MenuProcessor.java:106)
>       at com.mycompany.processor.MenuProcessor.modifyModelAttributes(MenuProcessor.java:84)
>       at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.dialect.AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.processElement(AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor.java:46)
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementProcessor.doProcess(AbstractElementProcessor.java:74)
>       at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:896)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:858)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:639)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:621)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:876)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:639)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:621)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:876)
>       at org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:639).....

Comment: Where is the exception trace? Add it here, Add the code snap belong to that exception!

Comment: Why not post the code that breaks instead of the code that works?

Comment: Would you be so kind and give us the stacktrace and the line on which the error occurs ?

Comment: Giving [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces error instead of working code would let us figure out problem faster.

Comment: That's quite a stack trace!

Comment: Sorry I'm new so I'm not sure what part of that is needed

Comment: Would you be able to post what is on line 106 of MenuProcessor.java? I've copied the code, but the line numbers don't seem to match up :)

Comment: navigationMenu.put(topLvlCat, null);  - According to Oracle setting that null is allowed, correct?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that. That would have triggered a NPE 11 lines above (old comment: Is it possible that topLvlCat is null? While HashMap allows null keys, I'm not sure LinkedHashMap does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This weird problem just got stranger, it started working, even after deleting all the target folders and deployment folders and redoing the builds etc and not working, It has mysteriously started working the next day.

Answer (score 0):

If this line is truly throwing the nullpointer:

```
navigationMenu.put(topLvlCat, null);
```

Then navigationMenu is null. As linkedHashMap and HashMap both allow null keys and values.

I notice you are defining navigationMenu as a `public` field, meaning it can be changed by any class. This is bad practice you should declare fields as `private` and provide getter and if necessary setter methods.

So although you are initialising it, something else may be setting it back to null. I would check that there is nothing that could be setting the navigationMenu in another class or template file.

Comment: But why would it work as a regular HashMap? and not not work as a LinkedHashMap?